# Access-control-allow-origin header not getting updated

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to manually set the Access-origin header.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
<form method="post">
    <button style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" type="submit"></button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function start(){
        fetch("http://localhost:5500/")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
    }
</script>
```

Node:

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors({
    origin: "*"
}   
))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({name: "lukas"})
  
})

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("hej")
})
```

The error i am getting is a 405 method not allowed.

This is the response:

[image: network panel]

Responses are empty.

What should i do to make this right?

Comment: `{name: lukas}` should be `{name: "lukas"}`. Have you restarted your Express server since adding the CORS middleware?

Comment: _"my IP:Port is listed in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response-header"_... it shouldn't be. The response header should be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` since that's how you've configured the middleware. More confusing, the error message says it's not there at all. So which is it?

Comment: Sorry @Phil, right now i am getting a simple 405 from the console. The response-header is not changing though.

Comment: There's too much conflicting information here. 1) Restart your Express server so you're sure it's using the latest code changes. 2) Open your browser dev-tools _Network_ panel and inspect the request made... what method is it using? What response headers are present? What is the response body (use the _Response_ tab ). [Edit] your question to include screenshots from the _Network_ panel

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows a POST request but the code you've shown only uses GET. Please [edit] your question with the **actual code**, both client-side and server-side

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with CORS or even Express. Your HTML form (which you only just added in your [last edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74008844/6)) submits to your front-end server. If you wanted to submit to your Express server, you should have `action="http://localhost:3000/"`. The `fetch()` call you make is also redundant and will just respond with the HTML

Answer (score -1):

It's failing because POST method is not allowed so you need to change that

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]  // you can put all the methods you need here
}   
))
```

Comment: I tried it, but there seems to be a problem with even editing anything in the headers. Neither origin or methods are changed doing this.

Comment: The `cors()` defaults already include those methods and more

Comment: @Phil I already know that, but the error presented clearly stated that POST is not allowed and if you look at the response headers in Allow attribute it doesn't have POST among them

Comment: @ottdevott are you sure you are restarting the server after updating?

Comment: If it was a CORS problem, the error would be something like _"request method POST is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods"_. OP is instead getting a 405 response because they're sending a POST request to what is probably VSCode's Live Server instead of the Express server

Comment: @Mustafa yes, i've got nodemon installed. Adding action="http://localhost:3000" bypasses the 405, but the post-request does not get processed. This is the new headers that are coming. https://i.postimg.cc/Fs8ytpD4/Untitled3.png

Comment: The console is giving me this message: "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."